# Forwarding request to tomcat's error-page

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have the following in my web.xml:

```
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/error/exception</location>
    </error-page>
```

The path `/error/exception` is a servlet.

My question is: is there a way to forward the request that caused the exception to the error-page defined in the web.xml?

Comment: That should work fine. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: @BalusC The above creates a new request, I want the request body of the request that caused the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The above creates a new request*

This is not true. Unless you're sending a redirect inside the servlet of course, but that would be a too obvious mistake.

---

> *I want the request body of the request that caused the exception.*

The request body can be read only once. The client ain't going to resend it once again whenever you want to read it once again. In case of normal `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST requests, the server will read and parse the request body into request parameters as you get by `HttpServletRequest#getParameterMap()`. If you don't want to display all request parameters in a nice list/table for some unobvious reason, then you can also just reconstruct the request body based on the request parameter map. E.g.

```
String requestBody = toQueryString(request.getParameterMap());
// ...
```

with

```
public static String toQueryString(Map<String, String[]> params) {
    StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder();

    for (Entry<String, String[]> param : params.entrySet()) {
        for (String value : param.getValue()) {
            if (queryString.length() > 0) {
                queryString.append("&amp;");
            }

            queryString
                .append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"))
                .append("=")
                .append(URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
        }
    }

    return queryString.toString();
}
```

In case of `multipart/form-data` requests, well, that depends on how you're parsing the request body and storing the data. Reconstructing is also less trivial.

If you want a completely transparent solution, consider a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` which copies the request body to a local (byte) buffer (or temp file when it exceeds a certain threshold) whenever `getInputStream()` or `getReader()` is called. Then, just cast the `HttpServletRequest` to your wrapper implementation and grab that copy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I used an HttpServletRequestWrapper.